# Ember helper has undefined values

Tags: ember.js

I can't figure out why the helper I created in `app/helpers/shop-name.js`:

```
import { helper } from '@ember/component/helper';

export function shopName(shop) {
  return shop.identifier + '-' + shop.name;
}

export default helper(shopName);
```

doe not format the values as needed in my template `application.hbs`:

```
<select>
  {{#each model as |shop|}}
    <option value={{shop.id}}>{{shop-name shop}}</option>
  {{/each}}
</select>
```

I get `undefined-undefined` displayed in my select list.

If I do the same conversion directly in the template:

```
<option value={{shop.id}}>{{shop.identifier}}-{{shop.name}}</option>
```

it works as needed. What's wrong with that helper ?

I'm using Ember 3.0.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that helpers can take inputs that aren't strings.  I hope someone can confirm.

Anyway, your use case is really better handled at the model level, using a computed property:

```js
shopName: computed('identifier', 'name', function() {
  return `${identifier} - ${name}`;
})
```

and then you would just use `{{shop.shopName}}` in your template

Comment: I'm getting `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getAttribute' of undefined`. I imported computed as follows: `import EmberObject, { computed } from '@ember/object';`, then added the above snippet.

Comment: Ah, my bad, I figured out how to use and call the computed method: add `import {computed} from '@ember/object';` to `shop` model, call the `shopName` from the template: `shop.shopName`.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple issues in your code.

1. `shop` is an object and I bet it's an `Ember.Object`. If dealing with `Ember.Object`s, you should always use `get()` method to retrieve values for now. This [might change soon](https://github.com/emberjs/rfcs/blob/master/text/0281-es5-getters.md). Since you are not using `get()` method, you get `undefined`. Embers template engine is using getter and therefore it's a huge difference between `shop.identifier` in your helper and `{{shop.identifier}}` in your template. Resolve the issue by `shop.get('identifier')` or `import { get } from '@ember/object'; [...] get(shop, 'identifier');` Use the last one if you can't be sure that `shop` is an instance of `Ember.Object`.
2. Since you are passing `shop` and not `shop.identifier` as argument to your helper, the helper will only be recomputed if the reference of `shop` changes (e.g. replaced by another object). Changes to the value of it's properties will not recompute the helper.

One solution for you problem is to use a computed property as suggested by ctcpip. Another one is the [`concat` helper](https://emberjs.com/api/ember/3.0/classes/Ember.Templates.helpers/methods/concat?anchor=concat): `{{concat shop.identifier '-' shop.name}}`.

Comment: thanks a lot for such a detailed explanation. Really useful.